# How to reuse Redis connection inside Typeorm cache config in NestJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, node-redis

I am using Redis to cache queries inside TypeOrm.

but the problem is, TypeOrm and Redis package is opening the separate connection, i just want to reuse the same connection for both.

this is typeorm config:

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Constants } from '../utils/Constants';

export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: Constants.DB_TYPE,
    host: Constants.DB_HOST,
    port: Constants.DB_PORT,
    username: Constants.DB_USER_NAME,
    password: Constants.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: Constants.DB_NAME,
    entities: [ __dirname + '/../**/*.entity.{js,ts}' ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    cache: {
        type: 'ioredis',
        duration: 60000,
        options: {
            host: 'localhost',
            password: 'swapnil',
            port: 6379
        }
    },
    extra: {
        max: 10,
        connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000
    }
};
```

i am using [@svtslv/nestjs-ioredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svtslv/nestjs-ioredis) package for redis:

```
import { Constants } from '../utils/Constants';

export const config = {
    host: Constants.REDIS_HOST,
    port: parseInt(Constants.REDIS_PORT),
    db: parseInt(Constants.REDIS_DB),
    password: Constants.REDIS_PASSWORD
};
```

and using this package, i am able to access redis inside my service class using:

```
public constructor(@InjectRedis() private readonly redis: Redis,) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging in the TypeORM code base I came across two solutions (wiil one the other is a bit hacky and my case issues)

### ORM CustomQueryResultCache

According to the doc, you can implement your own cache handler see: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/caching.md.

This is the better but harder solution due to the Interface that need to be implemented https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/cache/QueryResultCache.ts

In addition, you will need you register the TypeOrmModule with [forRootAsync](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration) to first be able to connect to Redis.

### Hacky fun times

According to the code base, you should be able to access the Redise client (connection) that TypeORM is creating.

On the type ORM `connection` there is a member called `connection.queryResultCache` for managing the cache.
But furthermore there is a member name `client` on the queryResultCache (`connection.queryResultCache.client`)

See TypeORM redis Cache implamatation:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/cache/RedisQueryResultCache.ts

```
import { Connection } from 'typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {

    connection.queryResultCache.client // <-- Cache client.
  }
}
```

But it goes without saying that this is not the intended uses and this will couple your DB to Redis which is not that grate for future-proofing your codebase.

### My honest opinion

According to the idea of **separation of concerns** I would recommend sticking with two connections instead of one just to keep the `DB query Cache` and the standard `Cache` separated.

This will allow you more flexibility in the future for integration testing and refactoring.

See: https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/issues/59

Comment: Opening multiple connections can cause overhead?

Comment: I don't see this as overhead due to the fact each `Redis` connection servers a different job (Although they are both hosted together). If you what **optimization** you should go for the first solution.